# Dynamics 365 Customer Service : Email sent from one queue to another queue is getting linked to same ticket

Tags: dynamics-crm, case, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am facing an issue in Dynamics 365.

Let's say I have 2 queues - Queue1 & Queue2 and have enabled case creation rule on both the queues. Initially, the customer sent an email to Queue1 and converted it into the case, and I want to forward this email to Queue2.

When I forward email FROM Queue1 TO Queue2, it comes back as 'incoming' email to Dynamics through Queue2, but again gets linked to the same old case present in Queue1.  I want that, it should create a new case in Queue2.

I tried a pre-create plugin also to clear regardingobject in an incoming email if the sender is a Dynamics queue and as per traces, code is clearing regardingobectid as well. However, it still gets linked to the same ticket somehow.

Is there anyone who faced the same issue and got a workaround.

Plugin code snippet - registered on Email Pre-create sync.

````
TargetEntity = (Entity)PluginContext.InputParameters["Target"];

var sender = TargetEntity["sender"].ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
EntityCollection senderQueue = GetQueue(sender);

if (senderQueue?.Entities != null && senderQueue.Entities.Count != 0)
{
  TracingService.Trace("sender is a queue");

  TracingService.Trace("updating : TargetEntity['regardingobjectid'] = null to platform");

  TargetEntity["regardingobjectid"] = null;
}```
````

Comment: Did you check the tracking token and correlation Id being appended to the email?

Comment: I was finally able to do it. :)

Comment: Then post your answer for others finding it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do it after clearing 3 attributes in the incoming email's target entity.

I have written a pre-validate sync plugin on email cleared below 3 fields :-

```
TargetEntity["regardingobjectid"] = null;
// this line -- parentactivityid fixed the issue.
TargetEntity["parentactivityid"] = null;
TargetEntity["trackingtoken"] = null;
```

Comment: Did you run these three lines of code inside of the "if"-statement in your first post? You say in your second post that one of the lines solved the issue. Were the other two lines that set regardingobjectid and trackingtoken to null also necessary?